# My MacBook webcam not working properly for my python project

Tags: python

I am trying to build an face recognition python project for that the project needs to access my MacBook webcam

Initially after successful compilation it asked me to allow access  to webcam and I allowed it but now the cam only shows black screen

what would be the issue here?

this is my code

```
import face_recognition 
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
import csv #for csv file
import os 
from datetime import datetime #to get exact date and time

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
jobs_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("/Users/dhruvijoshi/Desktop/facerecognitionproject/photos/jobs.jpeg")
jobs_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(jobs_image) [0]
ratan_tata_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("/Users/dhruvijoshi/Desktop/facerecognitionproject/photos/tata.jpeg")
ratan_tata_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(ratan_tata_image)[0]
sadmona_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("/Users/dhruvijoshi/Desktop/facerecognitionproject/photos/sadmona.jpeg")
sadmona_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(sadmona_image)[0]
tesla_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("/Users/dhruvijoshi/Desktop/facerecognitionproject/photos/tesla.jpeg")
tesla_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(tesla_image)[0]

known_face_encoding=[
jobs_encoding,
ratan_tata_encoding,
sadmona_encoding,
tesla_encoding
]
known_faces_names=[
"jobs",
"ratan tata",
"sadmona",
"tesla"
]

students = known_faces_names. copy ()

face_locations =[]
face_encodings=[]
face_names =[]
s=True

now = datetime.now()
current_date=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

f= open(current_date+'.csv', 'w+' ,newline='')
lnwriter = csv.writer(f)
while True:
    _,frame = video_capture.read ()
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0) , fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
    rgb_small_frame= small_frame [:,:,::-1]
    if s:
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)
        face_names=[]
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encoding, face_encoding)
            name=""
            face_distance = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encoding, face_encoding)
            best_match_index =np.argmin(face_distance)
            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name=known_faces_names[best_match_index]

            face_names.append(name)
            if name in known_faces_names:
                if name in students:
                    students.remove(name)
                    print(students)
                    current_time = now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
                    lnwriter.writerow ([name,current_time])
    cv2.imshow("attendence system",frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('g'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
f.close()
```